# List filtering+counting vs. directly counting? Weird test results

Tags: list, racket, counting

This is about counting how many elements in a list fulfill a given test.

I saw this function

```
(define (numsof p lst)
  (length (filter p lst)))
```

and thought that it would be inefficient because it has to go over two lists, the initial one for filtering and then counting the result with `length`. So I implemented this to directly count how many elements fulfill the test `p`.

```
 (define (amount p lst [acc 0])
  (if (empty? lst)
      acc
      (amount p (cdr lst) (if
                           (p (car lst))
                           (add1 acc)
                           acc))))
```

Following that I ran some tests as follows with a helper function:

```
; Creates list of natural numbers in [0, range) of given length
(define (random-list length range)
  (if (zero? length)
      null
      (cons (random range) (random-list (sub1 length) range))))

(for ([i 10])
  (display "numsof: ") (time (numsof odd? (random-list 999999 9999999)))
  (display "amount: ") (time (amount odd? (random-list 999999 9999999)))
  (displayln ""))
```

Now the results I got were quite unexpected for me as I thought my definition `amount` should be about twice as fast as `numsof`, but I'm not really into algorithmic performance yet so this guess may be obviously false for you anyway.

Here, have some test results y'all:

```
numsof: cpu time: 2875 real time: 2710 gc time: 2060
amount: cpu time: 2578 real time: 2590 gc time: 1872

numsof: cpu time: 1484 real time: 1494 gc time: 719
amount: cpu time: 2547 real time: 2586 gc time: 1779

numsof: cpu time: 2422 real time: 2449 gc time: 1748
amount: cpu time: 2593 real time: 2608 gc time: 1843

numsof: cpu time: 1375 real time: 1360 gc time: 658
amount: cpu time: 2641 real time: 2662 gc time: 1842

numsof: cpu time: 2609 real time: 2593 gc time: 1873
amount: cpu time: 1406 real time: 1400 gc time: 655

numsof: cpu time: 2640 real time: 2652 gc time: 1938
amount: cpu time: 1360 real time: 1384 gc time: 623
```

Can someone please explain to me if my function is the faster or slower one; in any case, why? And what is going on with the test results, I can't make any sense of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: Most of this is just plain wrong. Skip to "**UPDATE: JUST READ THIS**" at the end.

I get similar results.

A possible explanation would be if Racket `list`s -- which are immutable, remember -- store their length, so that `length` is simply looking up a value like a struct member, as opposed to traversing all the list elements. (I vaguely recall reading something like this on the Racket mailing list, but unfortunately can't find it right now.)

Possible evidence for is, would be to see if `length` takes appreciably longer as the size of the list increases:

```
(for ([len (in-list (list 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000))])
  (define xs (build-list len values))
  (time (length xs)))

cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
cpu time: 1 real time: 0 gc time: 0
cpu time: 4 real time: 3 gc time: 0
```

OK, the last two timings are non-zero. But they are very small. For practical purposes, O(1), not O(n), even for fairly large n.

---

**UPDATE**

Actually, I skipped a big step. My answer explains what I thought your prose was asking, not the test code you showed. I think the test code you meant -- that actually fits with your question -- would be something like this:

```
(for ([i 10])
  (define xs (random-list 999999 9999))
  (display "numsof: ") (time (numsof odd? xs))
  (display "amount: ") (time (amount odd? xs))
  (displayln ""))
```

This creates a random list, then times only `numsof` vs. `amount` per se running on that list.

This gives basically the same timings for both `numsof` and `amount`.

And an explanation for this would be if `length` is effectively O(1) because Racket lists store their length.

As for why your original, provided test code shows such different results among invocations of `random-list`? I think that's simply due to memory allocation and garbage collection times being less predictable.

---

## **UPDATE: JUST READ THIS**

Almost everything I said in this answer turns out to be wrong. Specifically:

- `length` does not cache. `list?` does.
- I broke the first rule of profiling. I didn't use plain command-line Racket. As a result, my measurements were affected by `errortrace` annotations.
- Also, I probably should have used `(for ([_ 3]) (collect-garbage))` before each `time`, to focus on the algorithms independent of garbage collection time.

About the only value in my original answer is the idea that, for sufficiently small lists, it is probably fine to do things like compose `length` and `filter`.  But really, that's an obvious answer to a question like, "Are there ever times when it's OK to favor clarity of expression over speed?". And a shorter answer to the question would be, "Yes, it depends".

Comment: I've thought to remember HTDP discusses the trade offs when implementing lists between storing the length with the list and not computing it. IIRC the teaching language, in conclusion, doesn't store the length. Maybe Racket handles it differently though. Will look into it, thanks.